# Why are the last few lines missing from a text file that I'm creating?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I have a function that creates 7 different text files with rows of data.  Those 7 files are then combined into a single file in a different function using the following function:

```
public void createSingle683File(int groupNumber, FileWriter wr){
        try{
            if(new File(printDir+"683_"+groupNumber+".txt").exists()){
                File f683 = new File(printDir+"683_"+groupNumber+".txt");
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f683));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null){
                    //write contents of existing file to new file
                    wr.write(line+"\n");
                }
                //close bufferedInput
                input.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The calling code:

```
    File fileHandle683 = new File(printDir+"683.txt");
                FileWriter wr683 = new FileWriter(fileHandle683);
                for (int groupNumber = 1; groupNumber < 8; groupNumber++){
                    createSingle683File(groupNumber,wr683);
                }
.
.
.
.
.//stuff
wr683.close();
```

Alaways the final 683.txt is missing about 50 lines from the 7th file (683_7.txt) and I can't figure out why.  It's always, and only, the last few lines of the final file that are missing.  I can't tell if I am closing the bufferInput to soon or what.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  I can test any ideas really quickly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see where you are closing `wr683`. I suspect that the data is being left in a buffer when the process shuts down. At least call `flush()`.

Comment: what does flush() do that close() does not?

Comment: It writes all the data to disk but leaves the writer open for more output. Useful if you want to continue writing but also want to minimize chances of losing data written so far.

Comment: Yes, I step through and see that it is getting called. I just added the flush() to the for loop for each of the 7 files and this fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: calling `close()` also flushes the file - so this would seem to imply that the code to `close()` the writer is never reached

Comment: @northpole - that's very strange. Like @matt says, calling `close()` _should_ automatically call `flush()`. There may be a bug somewhere in the Java library (very unlikely for this, though), or perhaps you have multiple threads accessing the file and/or `wr683`. Or could it be that `wr683` is getting reassigned inside `//stuff`?

Comment: matt, that's why I was asking about the differences. I am now checking the production logs to see if an exception is thrown before the close().  Which I assume will be yes.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @matt/@Ted, yes embarrassingly enough, there is an exception happening before the closing of the writer.  I should have realized this was causing the problem.  I am sorry to take up your time on such a silly oversight.  Thanks again!

Comment: @northpole, make sure you call `flush()`/`close()` in a finally block to prevent that type of thing in the future

Answer (score 4):

Are you calling `flush()` and/or `close()` on that FileWriter instance?

Comment: yes, I close the wr683 at the end of the function using wr683.close();

Comment: Are you sure that the `close()` is being executed?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are not closing the file writer for the final file. So it may be, that the contents you are missing currently are still in the cache of the stream I/O. So close the FileWriter instance of the final file and look at the contents of the file.

So after the for loop you simply enter

> wr683.close();

Hope it helps.